# PostgreSQL large table SELECT/INSERT performance?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am in the process of designing a database layout to run on PostgreSQL. In this database i need to handle a lot of addresses, so I naturally want to use an address table and then have my other data just point at the primary key.

I want addresses to be unique, so i plan on using a simple primary key and then a unique index on all of the data columns.

Something along the lines of this:

```
CREATE TABLE address(id serial NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(32), address1 VARCHAR(32), address2 VARCHAR(32), postal VARCHAR(12), city VARCHAR(64), CONSTRAINT pkey PRIMARY KEY (id), CONSTRAINT unq UNIQUE (name,address1,address2,postal,city));
```

I anticipate that there will be well over 2 million entries in this table from day one.

The table will be hit by a lot of simultaneous SELECTS and also a few INSERTS. But for data integrity purposes the table will never see UPDATES or DELETES.

What sort of performance can i expect from this kind of table? Is there any performance penalty to using large tables rather than copying the data to where it is needed?

Comment: It simple to test. Use your favorite scripting language to generate 2 million sets of random strings, make sure they're unique (either by careful scripting or by `sort -u`) and load them into the database. For testing, it doesn't matter whether the address looks like an address.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how many this queries will be, how strong is your machine, is there a good index that can be used for each query... Generally 2 millions rows for PostgreSQL it isn't a big number, when the query results are good restricted by indexes, especially the search by primary key will be efficient.

But, however, searching via `LIKE`, with wildcard on beginning, would be a performance issue.

Comment: Since 9.1, PostgreSQL is capable of using an index for `LIKE` operation, see: http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/

Comment: The GIN index sounds interesting... I guess ill just have to run a few tests and see for myself.